# Merge two objects when there's a new key

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, merge

I have two objects with the following structure and tried to merge them together.

I tried it with $.merge but its not the expected result.

**Object 1 - Has not all attributes**

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Article",
    "related": 15 "items": [{
        "name": "Test1",
        "items": [{
            "name": "Test2",
            "items": [{
                "name": "Test3",
                "items": [{
                    "name": "Test4",
                    "items": [{
                        "name": "Test5",
                        "items": [{
                            "name": "Test6",
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": 24…
}
```

**Object 2 - with additional attributes**

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Article",
    "related": 15 "items": [{
        "name": "Test1",
        "id": 34 "items": [{
            "name": "Test2",
            "id": 57 "items": [{
                "name": "Test3",
                "id": 92 "items": [{
                    "name": "THIS ONE IS NOT EXISTING IN OBJECT 1 AND SHOULD NOT GET MERGED",
                    "id": 789
                }, {
                    "name": "Test4",
                    "id": 12 "items": [{
                        "name": "Test5",
                        "id": 321 "items": [{
                            "name": "Test6",
                            "id": 285
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": 24…
}
```

Does anyone know some smart trick? Is jQuery even necessary?

Comment: no need for jquery, you needs 1 or 2 for loops, and one recursive function.

Comment: @nem: "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web". Best tip ever

Comment: It's not clear what you ask for. Object 2 is already the merge of Object 1 and 2, so just take Object 2 and you're done. Maybe you mean when both have "something new"?

Comment: @pid I have to objects and where one has different additional attributes. The merged object should contain these.

Comment: You realize that the example you gave is not a good one? It is unnecessarily cumbersome and does not show the general case when both have new attributes. Furthermore, do you realize that you can have COLLISIONS? If both redefine the same attribute with different values which one do you take? Normally, collisions cannot be handled and should throw an exception.

Comment: @pid: I just edited the description to get it more clear

Comment: Criteria is far too loosely outlined here. Also not clear if these objects will each be updated and co-exist in page together or if one is *fresh data* from server .... so in general, the overall objective is not well defined

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's $.extend will do what you want.

```
//merging two objects into new object
var new_object = $.extend(true, {}, object1, object2);

//merge object2 into object1
$.extend(true, object1, object2);
```

The 1st parameter: deep:true, see: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 1):

Without jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/sLhcbewh/

```
function mymerge_sub(object1, object2)
{
  for(var i in object2) {
    if(i == 'items')
      continue;

    console.log(i);
    if(object1[i] === undefined) {
      console.log(i + ' not found');
      object1[i] = object2[i];
    }
  }

  if(object1.items !== undefined) {
    mymerge_sub(object1.items[0], object2.items[0])
  }
}

function mymerge(object1, object2) {
  var ret = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object1));
  mymerge_sub(ret, object2); // save obj 1
  return ret;
}

var obj3 = mymerge(obj1, obj2);
```

If you want several items, you have to loop mymerge_sub(object1.items[j]... ).

Comment: @charlietfl: he asks for a merge on new keys, he didnt tell that he wanted to merge  on existant keys. If so, he has to remove one condition in this code (omg).

Comment: merge and overwrite aren't the same thing though. Also note that the objects are now references of each other. Not clear if that's ok or not

Comment: … i edited the description. I think the first description was misleading.